# How to bind mount a Windows directory without overwriting Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to bind mount my project directory so that my code updates real-time in the Docker container. From a tutorial that I've been following, this code seemed to work for them in Mac:

```
docker run -p 80:80 --rm --name backend --network docker-demo -v /app/node_modules -v logs:/app/logs -v /$(pwd):/app:ro backend
```

where `-v /$(pwd):/app:ro` binds the Windows project folder to the container folder and `-v /app/node_modules` makes the `node_modules` folder in the container to not be overwritten when `npm install` is run.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here's the tree directory:

```
C:/Users/$username/Documents/docker-demo/
├───backend
│   │   .dockerignore
│   │   app.js
│   │   Dockerfile
│   │   package.json
│   │
│   ├───logs
│   │       access.log
│   │
│   └───models
│           goal.js
```

The container works with anonymous and named volume but not when the bind mount command is included.

Comment: I generally recommend deleting these mounts entirely: in the setup you show you're not using any of the code in the image, just its Node interpreter, and it's much easier to just install Node on the host than to try to use it indirectly via a container.

Comment: Yes, it was disclosed in the tutorial. I'm just trying to learn Docker and I just want to know how this one works.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what happens?